# GraphQL - Relationship returning null

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I started to learn GraphQL and I'm trying to create the following relationship:

```
type User {
  id: ID!,
  name: String!,
  favoriteFoods: [Food]
}

type Food {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  recipe: String
}
```

So basically, a user can have many favorite foods, and a food can be the favorite of many users. I'm using *graphql.js*, here's my code:

```js
const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Person',
    description: 'Represents a Person type',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        favoriteFoods: {type: GraphQLList(Food)},
    })
})

const Food = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Food',
    description: 'Favorite food(s) of a person',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        recipe: {type: GraphQLString}
    })
})
```

And here's the food data:

```js
let foodData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Lasagna', recipe: 'Do this then that then put it in the oven'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Pancakes', recipe: 'If you stop to think about, it\'s just a thin, tasteless cake.'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Cereal', recipe: 'The universal "I\'m not in the mood to cook." recipe.'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Hashbrowns', recipe: 'Just a potato and an oil and you\'re all set.'}
]
```

Since I'm just trying things out yet, my resolver basically just returns a user that is created inside the resolver itself. My thought process was: put the food IDs in a *GraphQLList*, then get the data from *foodData* usind *lodash* function *find()*, and replace the values in *person.favoriteFoods* with the data found.

```js
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    description: 'Root Query',
    fields: {
        person: {
            type: Person,
            resolve(parent) {
                let person = {
                    name: 'Daniel',
                    favoriteFoods: [1, 2, 3]
                }

                foodIds = person.favoriteFoods
                for (var i = 0; i < foodIds.length; i++) {
                    person.favoriteFoods.push(_.find(foodData, {id: foodIds[i]}))
                    person.favoriteFoods.shift()
                }

                return person
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But the last food is returning null. Here's the result of a query:

```
query {
  person {
    name
    favoriteFoods {
      name
      recipe
    }
  }
}

# Returns
{
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "name": "Daniel",
      "favoriteFoods": [
        {
          "name": "Lasagna",
          "recipe": "Do this then that then put it in the oven"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pancakes",
          "recipe": "If you stop to think about, it's just a thin, tasteless cake."
        },
        null
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is it even possible to return the data from the *Food* type by using only its ID? Or should I make another query just for that? In my head the relationship makes sense, I don't think I need to store the IDs of all the users that like a certain food in the *foodData* since it has an ID that I can use to fetch the data, so I can't see the problem with the code or its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `shift` and `push` on an array while iterating through that same array will invariably lead to some unexpected results. You could make a copy of the array, but it'd be much easier to just use `map`:

```
const person = {
  name: 'Daniel',
  favoriteFoods: [1, 2, 3],
}

person.favoriteFoods = person.favoriteFoods.map(id => {
  return foodData.find(food => food.id === id)
})

return person
```

The other issue here is that if your schema returns a `Person` in another resolver, you'll have to duplicate this logic in that resolver too. What you really should do is just return the person with `favoriteFoods: [1, 2, 3]`. Then write a separate resolver for the `favoriteFoods` field:

```
resolve(person) {
  return person.favoriteFoods.map(id => {
    return foodData.find(food => food.id === id)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So my schema is valid, then? Or do you think it'd be better if I created a field called userID in my Food type that stores all users id that like a type of food?